# Choosing the right isomorphisms

Tags: vector-spaces, category-theory, abelian-categories

The question makes sense in every abelian category, but for the moment let's work in the category of vector spaces over a field.

Suppose we have two exact sequences
$$ 0\to A \to B \to C \to D \to E \to 0 $$
and
$$ 0\to E' \to D' \to C' \to B' \to A' \to 0 $$
where $A\cong A'$, $B\cong B'$ and so on.

Is it **always** possible to choose vertical isomorphisms such that the following diagram is commutative?
$$
\newcommand{\la}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xleftarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{llllllllllll}
0 & \;\;\ra{} \;& A & \;\ra{} & B & \;\;\ra{} & C & \;\;\ra{} & D & \;\;\ra{} & E & \;\;\ra{} & 0 \\
 & & \da{\;} & & \da{\;} & & \da{\;} & & \da{\;} & & \da{\;} & & \\
0 & \;\;\la{} \;& A' & \;\la{} & B' & \;\;\la{} & C' & \;\;\la{} & D' & \;\;\la{} & E' & \;\la{} & 0 \\
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is almost never the case.

The reason is that in your diagram, $D\rightarrow D'$ cannot be an isomorphism since its kernel is the image of $C\rightarrow D$ and its image is the kernel of $D'\rightarrow C'$ (unless $C=C'=0$).

Comment: Why do you say the kernel of $D\to D'$ is the image of $C\to D$ ? Only the rows are exact in the diagram

Comment: Because $D\rightarrow D'$ is equal to the composite $D\rightarrow E\rightarrow E'\rightarrow D'$ if your diagram is commutative as you requested. Now, since $E\rightarrow E'$ is iso and $E'\rightarrow D'$ is mono...

Comment: Thanks, so silly of me not to notice this! It's funny that in the question I ask "is it ALWAYS.." and actually it is NEVER so =D