# Choice of the right isomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory, abelian-categories

The question makes sense in every abelian category, but for the moment let's work in the category of vector spaces over a field.

PS: I previously posted a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/599982/3416) which didn't make a lot of sense. This corrected one should! Notice that the bottom row in the diagram below has the arrows reversed.

Suppose we have two exact sequences
$$ 0\to A \to B \to C \to D \to E \to 0 $$
and
$$ 0\to A' \to B' \to C' \to D' \to E' \to 0 $$
where $A\cong A'$, $B\cong B'$ and so on.

Is it **always** possible to choose vertical isomorphisms such that the following diagram is commutative?
$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\xrightarrow{#1}}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\sum}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{llllllllllll}
0 & \ra{} & A & \ra{} & B & \ra{} & C & \ra{} & D & \ra{} & E & \ra{} & 0 \\
 & & \da{\sim} & & \da{\sim} & & \da{\sim} & & \da{\sim} & & \da{\sim} & & \\
0 & \ra{} & A' & \ra{} & B' & \ra{} & C' & \ra{} & D' & \ra{} & E' & \ra{} & 0 \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: I see you really want to close this question, but it is NOT a duplicate! The arrows in the diagram (bottom row) are reversed, and this makes a lot of difference. In particular the answer to the other question doesn't apply here

Comment: Indeed. Don't close this question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For finite-dimensional vector spaces: By simply counting the dimension we see that the image of $B \to C$ is isomorphic to the image of $B' \to C'$. This enables us to reduce the question to short exact sequences. But short exact sequences split, and for these the claim is obviously true: 
$$\begin{array}{c} 0 & \rightarrow & A & \rightarrow & A \oplus C & \rightarrow & C & \rightarrow & 0 \\ && f \downarrow ~~&& ~~~~~~~~~~ \downarrow(f,g) && g \downarrow ~~& \\ 0 & \rightarrow & A' & \rightarrow & A' \oplus C' & \rightarrow & C' & \rightarrow & 0\end{array}$$